# Can I make a Linq join asynchronous?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, asynchronous

I have the following linq and I would like to make it async to improve performance. Is this possible? As this is a join, I thought it would be possible to make it async because of performance but the commands I am using do not seem to have an async equivalent. Is there an equivalent and why not?

```
var usersindomain = allUsers
  .Join(allUserStatus, usr => usr.EIN, us => us.EIN, (usr,us) => new { usr,us})
  .Where(result => result.us.DomainID == id)
  .OrderBy(order => order.us.Status)
  .Select (z => new { EIN = z.usr.EIN, FullName = z.usr.FullName, Status = z.us.Status });
```

Comment: I really don't think that async would improve performances; maybe you can find a way to use AsParallel for that.

Comment: What framework is this? EF Core, and I think EF6 now, have asynchronous methods to realize query results.

Comment: The code you show doesn't do anything. It *can't* have an async equivalent. It's nothing but a query definition waiting to be executed.

Answer (score 4):

If the origin of this is `IQueryable<T>` where `allUsers` is coming from EF, then EF provides some custom extension APIs to perform asynchronous queries, as listed on [`EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions), including things like `.ToListAsync()`. The main intent of this is to perform the *remote SQL query* asynchronously.

If the data is already in memory, and you're using LINQ-to-Objects, then: no. There is a huge difference between "async" and "parallel"; performing something async locally *by itself* provides few to no gains, if it is CPU-bound rather than being blocked on an external resource. The point of "async" is to release threads that would be blocked (for example) on external IO; this doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 1):

As Marc Gravell mentions, there is little to no point of using 'real' async calls unless there is some kind of io involved.

There is however [.AsParallel()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.asparallel?view=net-5.0) that support [.Join()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.join?view=net-5.0) that you can try. You could also run the query on a background thread using [Task.Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-5.0) to move the execution from the main thread and avoid blocking.